# Wordpress style sheet loads but is not applied

Tags: css, wordpress

I am upgrading a server from a very old debian version to the latest. Re-installed the OS completely, then re-installed wordpress from scratch, installed the plugins needed, loaded the databases (this is a multi-site wordpress instance), installed the themes required. The pages load OK, and elements of the theme are present, but the CSS does not get applied (and in consequence the pages look awful.
The server is not yet on the public internet.
I've read multiple posts on this and followed the advice, but none have resolved the issue.

Debian is version 6.1.37-1, Wordpress is 6.2.2, all packages are up to date. Any pointers would be highly welcome. Any questions, please fire away and I will provide whatever output you may need.

I've read multiple posts on this and followed the advice, but none have resolved the issue.

Comment: Take a look at your browser's devtools console and Network tab. Do you see errors when the browser atttempts  to download .css files? This can sometimes happen when migrating WordPress sites from one origin URL to another.

Comment: Indeed there are errors shown in the console tab. Several style sheets are not loaded "because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css". Is there a way to disable that check or do I need to amend all these files?

Comment: The issue is not the files, it's your server configuration. Your web server is serving your CSS files with an incorrect mime type. Check how to configure mime types on your web server. If you are using a proxy like NGINX, you may also need to configure mime types there as well. Also, WordPress questions belong on the [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards the WordPress site, didn't know there was one. It's a little surprising, though, as the apache install is straight out of the box, so I would have expected this to work. Nevertheless, I'll do some digging around.